# get NS record for domain using dig

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, ns-record

I'm currently trying to write a script that validates, whether a given record attached to a name is available via all nameservers that are responsible for that name.

E.g. I would like to check whether there is an `A` record for `foo.example.com` available at all `NS` entries for the `example.com` domain (`a.iana-servers.net` and `b.iana-servers.net`)

The script works by first querying the `NS` records for the given name (or its parents if that fails; e.g. since `foo.example.com.` doesn't have an `NS` entry, we try `example.com.` next and finally `.com.`), and then checking the `A` record with all nameservers.

```
 name=foo.example.com
 # get the nameservers for ${name}
 sname=${name}
 until [ -z "x${sname}" ]; do
    dns=$(dig +short NS "${sname}")
    if [ "x${dns}" != "x" ]; then
      break
    fi
    sname=${sname#*.}
done
# now that we have a list of nameservers in $dns, we query them
for ns in $dns; do
    dig +short A "${name}" @$"{ns}"
done
```

This kind of works, **unless** the *name* is actually a `CNAME`.
In this case, a `dig NS` will return the `CNAME` record (rather than the `NS` record or *no* record)

```
$ dig +noall +answer NS foo.example.com
foo.example.com. 300 IN CNAME bar.example.com.
$ dig +short NS foo.example.com
bar.example.com.
$ dig A foo.example.com @bar.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
$
```

Instead I would like to have something like:

```
$ dig +short NS foo.example.com
$ dig +short NS example.com
a.iana-servers.net.
b.iana-servers.net.
$ dig +short A foo.example.com @a.iana-servers.net.
93.184.216.34
$
```

So my question is: how can I force `dig` to *only* return the `NS` records, and not some other record which points to a host that is not a nameserver?

One obvious solution is to parse the output of `dig +noall +answer` to see whether it actually contains an `NS` record, but this seems rather clumsy and error prone...

Comment: Although some systems violate the standard, officially there should NEVER be NS records for a name that has a CNAME record, nor any others except for DNSSEC; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#Restrictions . If foo.example.com CNAMEs to bar.example.com, you need to find the nameservers and thus A record(s) (or others) **for bar.example.com** (via its nearest apex).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 fine with me; however i'm interested in finding out the nameservers that are responsible for a given name (e.g. `foo.example.com`), not necessarily the `NS` record that is attached to that name literally. So I don't think that CNAME-restriction applies (after all, some nameserver must be authoritative to tell that `foo.example.com` *is* a `CNAME`; how do I find out which?)

Comment: `dig` has no option to filter specific types of records from the result set.

Comment: Since NS records can't be at the same level as CNAME they must be at a higher level. (This is usually stated as "CNAME cannot be at the [zone] apex" or "The apex cannot be a CNAME".) You already have the logic for this, since it is _often_ true of 'real' names as well.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so how do I detect from the output of `dig` that I actually queried a `CNAME`? neither `grep -w CNAME` nor using some other grep-strip (e.g. to match an IP) sounds particularily compelling or stable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're at all comfortable with Perl, you can save yourself a whole lot of pretty finicky work by writing your test as a plugin to [Zonemaster](https://github.com/dotse/zonemaster-engine). Its framework already has (correct) code to find the right set of name servers and send a query to all of them.

Comment: I would encourage using a solution like this as well, simply because the problem can more complicated than is currently being tested for. (glue record mismatch anyone?)

Answer (score 2):

Here is modified version of your script, which should work. It isn't exactly nice, but should work.

Warning - as *Andrew B* suggested in comments in Perl answer, this could be wrong way. There might be other edge cases than CNAME.

```
#!/bin/bash

domain=$1
soa_len=0

# first we find SOA to get domain for which we will find name servers
until [[ -z "${domain}" ]] || [[ "$soa_len" -gt 1 ]] ; do
    SOA=$(dig +short SOA "${domain}")
    soa_len=$(echo $SOA | awk '{ print NF }')

    # Returned SOA is not SOA but CNAME
    if [ "$soa_len" -eq 1 ]; then
        # set returned SOA (CNAME) as new domain and check again
        domain=$SOA
    # SOA is Empty
    elif [ "$soa_len" -eq 0 ]; then
        # remove one subdomain and check again
        domain=${domain#*.}
    fi
done

# Get NS records
NS=$(dig +short NS "${domain}")

# Print NS records each record on new line
for ns in $NS; do
    echo $ns
done
```